# Related table declarative databinding in wpf/xaml

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have been working through a very small-scale WPF project in order to familiarize myself with it while I read Nathan's book. I am attempting to do declarative binding on a single window with multiple tables from the same dataset. The schema (names have been changed to protect the innocent) is:     tblMany2--tblOne--tblMany1

XAML is below, but in short:

- I set the datacontext in the windows _loaded handler. I have tried both to the dataset and to the table which is the primary table conceptually (tblMany1).
- I set the ItemSource on a combo box to tblMany1.
- I set the ItemSource on a second combo box to the foreign key data relation (originally it was a tbo, but I've been working for a while).
- The idea is to control the second combo box (and other controls) by changing the first.
- The result so far is a blank entry in the second combobox with a debug output saying cannot find the property of whichever object I've set the ItemsSource to.

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace;system;assembly=mscorlib"
mc:Ignorable="d"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyProject"
xmlns:dx="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase" 
    Height="500"
    Width="700"
    d:DesignHeight="350" d:DesignWidth="525" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">

<Window.Resources>
    <!--Data-->


    <!--Styles-->
    <Style x:Key="buttonStyle">
        <Setter Property="Button.Width" Value="85" />
        <Setter Property="Button.Height" Value="30" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="chkImageStyle" TargetType="Image">
        <Setter Property="Image.Height" Value="25" />
        <Setter Property="Image.Width" Value="30" />
        <Setter Property="Image.Margin" Value="100,30,0,0" />
        <Setter Property="Image.Stretch" Value="Fill" />
        <Setter Property="Image.VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="checkmark.jpg" />
        <Setter Property="Image.Visibility" Value="hidden" />
    </Style>

    <!--Data Tempaltes-->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="tblMany1Date">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=tblMany1Date, StringFormat=d,dx:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="tblOneLink">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Path=tblOne.Link}">
                <Run Text="{Binding Path=tblOne.Name}" />
            </Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" Height="500" Width="750">
    <!-- Main Dockpanel-->
    <DockPanel Name="DockPanel1">

        <!-- NavPane -->
        <StackPanel Height="315" Background ="LightBlue" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Name="StackPanel1" Width="135">
            <Button Margin="5" Content="New" Name="btnNewOne" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}"/>
            <Label Margin="0" Content="ManyDate:" Name="lblDate" />

            <!--Primary Control-->
            <ComboBox Margin ="0" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=tblMany1}"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource tblMany1Date}" Height="23" Name="cboDate" Width="120"
          ForceCursor="False" AllowDrop="False" />

            <TextBlock Margin="-5" Visibility="Hidden"/>

            <Label Margin="0" Content="OneName:" Name="lblOneName" />

            <ComboBox Margin="0" ItemsSource="{Binding FK_tblMany1_tblOne}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource tblOneLink}" Name="cboOne" />

        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Viewbox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I see, you bind two comboboxes to the same data context.
But if I understand you correctly, you want the second combobox to display the items related with the selected item of the first combobox.

You can achieve this either in this way (change the datacontext):

```
<ComboBox DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=cboDate}" Margin="0" ItemsSource="{Binding FK_tblMany1_tblOne}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource tblOneLink}" Name="cboOne" />
```

Or in this way:

```
<ComboBox Margin="0" ItemsSource="{Binding tblMany1/FK_tblMany1_tblOne}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource tblOneLink}" Name="cboOne" />
```

The slash sign in the code`tblMany1/FK_tblMany1_tblOne` indicates that the binding takes the current item of the `tblMany1` collection and then takes the property `FK_tblMany1_tblOne` of that item.

**Edit**
Because there is only two tables and you want to display the same collection (but with different fields), the correct code might look so:

```
<ComboBox Margin="0" ItemsSource="{Binding tblMany1}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource tblOneLink}" Name="cboOne" />
```

Comment: Thank you--This helped on one of the relationships I was working with. But on this particular one, I'm still having issue. No matter what I do, it doesn't recognize the Foreign Key in this relationship. I have a feeling this is related to the "directionality" of the relationship -- the Selected Item to which I am binding is MANY side of the relationship, and the target property on the second combo box is the ONE side. Does this make sense?

Comment: @dansan Could you add a screenshot of the tables diagram to the question? It is important to know whether the property is a collection or a single object. In this case I need to know the type of the FK_tblMany1_tblOne and tblOne properties

Comment: unfortunately I am unable to post an image because I am so disreputable. However, tblMany1 is related to tblOne via the tblOne_name varchar(50) field. The Foreign key is tblMany1_tblOne_Name. The relationship is named FK_Many1_tblOne. Unfortunately, in the dataset designer, you don't see the property for the relationship in the many table, or only in the one table. This is why I suspect that as the issue, since I'm trying to navigate from the many to the one via data binding.

Comment: @dansan You can upload an image to imgur.com directly and post just a link. I updated my answer, and I think the main issue is because of confusing names of properties. In examples which I saw earlier there were clear names like Customers, Orders and the relationship CustomerOrders.

Comment: @dansan And Another important notice: You can bind through child relations only—you cannot bind up through parent relations. Maybe that's the cause. It would be better to create some c#-classes, fill them from your data source, and bind comboboxes to c# objects.

Comment: this last is truly the issue. It's in fact quite frustratingly inflexible at the moment. I can make the app do what I want in this situation by inverting the parent-child relationship in the designer, but this is obviously not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Something I didn't know: the importance of the parent-child settings in the dataset designer. I assumed that by inverting them, I would also be inverting the relationship. However, that is not the case. The problem all along was that the navigation/relationship property between tblMany1 and tblOne was defined by default opposite to the conceptual situation.

Thanks to vorrtex for critical info on "/" syntax.